# Firebase Google log in get credentials

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

In this example here we can re-authenticate an user by providing first the credentials which vary on the provider. However for google there is this example which says:

```
guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                  accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
```

How do I get `user.authentication`? There is no `authentication` property in `Auth.auth().currentUser`.

```
credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)

user.reauthenticate(with: credential) { (result, error) in
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind reauthentication is that for certain sensitive operations such as deleting an account, updating the primary email address, or changing the password, you want to make sure the user has recently signed in.

So what you want to do is

1. ask them to sign in
2. get the credential
3. perform `user.reauthenticate` with the fresh credential

The Swift docs have a concise example for this:

```swift
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
var credential: AuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

For a more detailed code sample, check out FirebaseUI ([FUIAccountSettingsOperation.m](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Auth/FirebaseAuthUI/AccountManagement/FUIAccountSettingsOperation.m#L145)), which does what I outlined above.